# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})g(x^n)\,dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, contest-math, alternative-proof

> Let $k\geq 1$ be an integer, $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a Riemannian integrable function and $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Calculate
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})g(x^n)\,dx,$$
> where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of the real number $x$.

This is W33 of [József Wildt International Mathematical Competition, 2021](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Eperfetti/lavori/Wildt-2021.pdf). Yesterday, I planned to ask this question here because I could only handle the case where $k=1$ at that time. However, when I was ready to click the button "Review your question", an idea suddenly came to my mind: Why not consider $g\equiv 1$ first? After 1 hour or 2, that idea became a full answer to this problem. Now I write it here. It is a little bit long, because I proved two lemmas that is useful for us.

**My question.** Is my proof presented below correct or not? Does there exist a shorter and more elegant proof?

**Lemma 1.** If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is measurable and bounded, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})\,dx=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx.$$
*Proof of Lemma 1.*
Firstly,
$$\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})\,dx=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\int_{\left(\frac mn\right)^{1/k}}^{\left(\frac {m+1}n\right)^{1/k}}f(nx^k-m)\,dx=\int_0^1\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac1{nk}f(t)\left(\frac{m+t}n\right)^{\frac1k-1}\,dt.$$
Let
$$f_n(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac1{nk}f(t)\left(\frac{m+t}n\right)^{\frac1k-1},\qquad n\geq 1, t\in(0,1].$$
For fixed $t\in(0,1]$, we have
$$f_n(t)\to f(t)\int_0^1 \frac1k u^{\frac1k-1}\,du=f(t),\qquad \text{as }\ \ n\to\infty.$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
 |f_n(t)|&\leq |f(t)|\frac1{nk}\left(\frac tn\right)^{\frac1k-1}+|f(t)|\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac1{nk}\left(\frac{m}n\right)^{\frac1k-1}\\
 &\leq |f(t)|\frac1{k}t^{\frac1k-1}+|f(t)|\frac1k\int_{1/n}^1\left(u-\frac1n\right)^{\frac1k-1}\,du\\
 &\leq \frac{\|f\|_{L^\infty}}{k}t^{\frac1k-1}+|f(t)|.
 \end{align*}
Therefore, DCT implies that $\int_0^1 f_n(t)\,dt\to\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$, concluding the proof of Lemma 1.

**Lemma 2.** If $f\in L^\infty(0,1)$, and $0<\eta\ll1$, then there exists a positive cosntant relying only on $k$, $C(k)>0$ such that
$$\int_{1-\eta}^1|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx\leq \left(\eta+\frac{C(k)}{n}\right)\|f\|_{L^1}.$$
*Proof of Lemma 2.*
Assume that $\left(\frac mn\right)^{1/k}\leq 1-\eta<\left(\frac {m+1}n\right)^{1/k}$ for some $m\geq \frac n2+1$, then
\begin{align*}
  \int_{1-\eta}^1|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx&\leq \int_{\left(\frac mn\right)^{1/k}}^1|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx\\
  &=\int_0^1|f(t)|\sum_{p=m}^{n-1}\frac1{nk}\left(\frac{p+t}n\right)^{\frac1k-1}\,dt\\
  &\leq \|f\|_{L^1}\sum_{p=m}^{n-1}\frac1{nk}\left(\frac{p}n\right)^{\frac1k-1}\\
  &\leq \|f\|_{L^1}\frac1k\int_{\frac mn}^1\left(u-\frac1n\right)^{\frac1k-1}\,du\\
  &\leq \|f\|_{L^1}\left[\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{\frac1k}-\left(\frac{m-1}n\right)^{\frac1k}\right].
 \end{align*}
Let $\phi(s)=s^{1/k}$ for $s\in(0,1]$, then
\begin{align*}
  \phi\left(\frac mn+\frac1n\right)-\phi\left(\frac mn-\frac1n\right)&\leq \frac2n\max_{1/2\leq s\leq 1}|\phi'(s)|=\frac{2^{2-\frac1k}}{nk}\\
  &=\frac1{nk}+\frac{C(k)}{n}=\frac1n\min_{1/2\leq s\leq 1}|\phi'(s)|+\frac{C(k)}{n}\\
  &\leq \phi(1)-\phi\left(1-\frac1n\right)+\frac{C(k)}{n}.
 \end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
 \int_{1-\eta}^1|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx&\leq \left(\phi\left(1-\frac1n\right)-\phi\left(\frac mn-\frac1n\right)\right)\|f\|_{L^1}\\
 &\leq \left(\phi(1)-\phi\left(\frac mn+\frac1n\right)+\frac{C(k)}{n}\right)\|f\|_{L^1}\\
 &\leq \left(\eta+\frac{C(k)}{n}\right)\|f\|_{L^1}.
 \end{align*}
This completes the proof of Lemma 2.

**Proof of the main problem.**
We prove
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})g(x^n)\,dx=g(0)\int_0^1f(x)\,dx.\tag{1}$$
For each $\epsilon>0$ and $0<\eta\ll1$, since $g$ is continuous at $x=0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(0)|\leq \epsilon$ for all $x\in[0,\delta]$. For $n$ large enough, we have $(1-\eta)^n<\epsilon$ and thus
$$|g(x^n)-g(0)|\leq \epsilon,\qquad \forall x\in[0,1-\eta].$$
Therefore, for all large $n$, we have
\begin{align*}
  &\ \ \ \left|\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})g(x^n)\,dx-g(0)\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right|\\
  &\leq\left|g(0)\int_0^1f(\{nx^k\})\,dx-g(0)\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right|+\int_0^1|f(\{nx^k\})||g(x^n)-g(0)|\,dx\\
  &\leq|g(0)|\left|\int_0^1f(\{nx^k\})\,dx-\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right|+\epsilon \int_0^{1-\eta}|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx+2\|g\|_{L^\infty}\int_{1-\eta}^1|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx\\
  &\leq|g(0)|\left|\int_0^1f(\{nx^k\})\,dx-\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right|+\epsilon \int_0^{1}|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx+2\|g\|_{L^\infty}\int_{1-\eta}^1|f(\{nx^k\})|\,dx.
 \end{align*}
By Lemma 1 and Lemma 2, taking $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ on each side gives that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_0^1 f(\{nx^k\})g(x^n)\,dx-g(0)\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right|\leq \epsilon\|f\|_{L^1}+2\eta\|g\|_{L^\infty}\|f\|_{L^1}.$$
Letting $\epsilon,\eta\to0$, we get $(1)$.

I would like to **express my gratitude** to anyone who are reading this long post. Comments or remarks on a easier proof, or improved results (*e.g.* convergence rates, the same conclusion under weaker conditions), or anything else related to this problem, are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second lemma is not really necessary. Note that a Riemannian integrable function is always bounded, you can bound the remaining as follows: For all $\epsilon>0$, \begin{align}&\limsup_n \left| \int_{0}^1 f\left( \left\{nx^k \right\} \right)\left( g(x^n) -g(0)\right)\mathrm{d} x \right|\\ \le &2\epsilon \|f\|_{\infty} \|g\|_{\infty}+\limsup_n  \int_{0}^{1-\epsilon} \| f\|_{\infty} \left|g(x^n) -g(0) \right|\mathrm{d} x= 2\epsilon \|f\|_{\infty} \|g\|_{\infty}.\end{align}
Thus, $$ \lim_n \left| \int_{0}^1 f\left( \left\{nx^k \right\} \right)\left( g(x^n) -g(0)\right)\mathrm{d} x \right|=0.$$
For the first lemma, I think your solution is already okay.

Comment: (+1) Good point! Thanks for your answer and patience!